# Configuring Qt creator for KDE applications

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, kde-plasma

I want to build some KDE applications. Here's what I did so far:

1. `sudo apt-get install kde-full`
2. add `LIBS += -lkdeui` in the `.pro` file of a project which used KDE libraries.

I am using the QtCreator and the above mentioned steps don't seem to be enough. Error message: `KApplication: no such file or directory`.

What are the steps to configure my system for KDE application development?

Comment: Make sure you have the KDE headers installed, (-dev packages for KDE). Search /usr/include for kapplication.h to make sure it's there.

Comment: yes. I have done that now. It's still not working.

Comment: the necessary package is `kdelibs5-dev`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to build a KDE project is use CMake, not QMake. I really recommend you this approach because some KDE applications, like plasmoids, can not be build correctly using QMake.

In addition you can use KDevelop, but if you prefer Qt Creator, you can use it with a CMake project without problems.

http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/CMake

Answer (score 1):

`KApplication.h` is typically located in `/usr/include/KDE` folder. Make sure you have it in your include path (i.e. `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/KDE`).